# What is the reason for different behavior of grep on using quantifier * in comparison to quantifier + ?

Tags: regex, command-line, grep

On a Linux command line, why does

```
echo "aa" | grep a*
```

work as expected (returns `aa`), but

```
echo "aa" | grep a+
```

return nothing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use `egrep -e PATTERN` or `grep -E -e PATTERN` (see [grep man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)),
or use escaping on the "+" like that - `echo "aa" | grep "\+"`

Comment: `By default, grep does not use regular expressions` Are you sure?

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Please unaccept it and accept [hwnd's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24328243/20938) instead.

Comment: @sat you are right, it looks like a limited version of RE.

Comment: Okay, this answer is correct now.  You might want to read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html) to put things in perspective.

Answer (score 2):

By default, grep uses [basic regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) and meta-characters like `+` lose their meaning and need to be escaped.

```
echo "aa" | grep a\+
```

Comment: The + is not supposed to match a literal `+`, it is a quantifier